# Grunt Browserify - set include, fallback path

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, browserify, commonjs

Is there any way to create **Grunt** task for **Browserify** to use **fallback** path?
Eg.

`require('./module.js)`

Check if `module.js` is in current directory, if not there, check some other directory?

```
    project1
     |- dir1
         |- mod1.js - has: require('./mod2.js')
         |- bundle.js - has: require('./mod1.js') and require('./mod2.js')
    project2
     |- dir2
         |- mod1.js 
         |- mod2.js
```

I already tried **[remapify](https://github.com/joeybaker/remapify)**, but it can only check one specific directory.
And I don't want to change require paths inside modules, everything should be done trough Grunt.

I want to override some app (dir2), so I want to get (copy to dir1) only modules which I need to change, and to leave all others in app directory.

Gruntfile is in `project1`. Modules are **CommonJS**. I'm using **[grunt-browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify)**.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little old now but it would be good to have an answer.

So, I asked myself a very similar question a couple of days ago and ended up doing basically what you want to do.

Using `browserifyOptions` from grunt-browserify like:

```
// Using grunt-browserify
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-browserify");

grunt.initConfig({
  browserify : {
    options : {
      browserifyOptions : {
        // keep in mind that paths are relative to Gruntfile.js
        paths: ["./first/path", "./second/path", "./and/so/on"]
      }
    },
    dist : {
      files: { "./path/to/dist.js" : "./path/to/src.js" }
    }
  },
});
```

And you will now be able to do:

```
var myModule = require("myModule");
```

> opts.paths is an array of directories that browserify searches when
>   looking for modules which are not referenced using relative path. Can
>   be absolute or relative to basedir. Equivalent of setting NODE_PATH
>   environmental variable when calling browserify command. - [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#var-b--browserifyfiles-or-opts)

Theoretically, it should follow the paths in order, the only problem I've had is that it looks through native node modules (util, fs, etc..) before even searching those paths.

What the quote is saying is that if you do:

```
var myModule = require("./myModule");
```

Browserify will look for the module following the relative path. When you remove the relative path:

```
var myModule = require("myModule");
```

it can search through the stablished paths in the options.

### Edit

I tested this and it works as expected. I have a module called myModule.js that is in "./current/directory", and I also have a module called myModule.js that is in "./modules/directory". Also, in current directory, I have the "src.js" that requires the module: `require("myModule");`. It looks in order through the paths and the first found is the one injected into `bundle.js` in this case.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  browserify : {

    dist : {
      options : {
        browserifyOptions : {
          // keep in mind that paths are relative to Gruntfile.js
          paths: ["./current/directory", "./modules/directory"]
        }
      },
      files: { "./current/directory/bundle.js" : "./current/directory/src.js" }
    }
  },
});
```